# restarting program after computer awakens

Tags: linux-mint, systemd, x-server

When my computer comes back from slumber, my program, cairo-dock, looks terrible. I don't know why the icons on it look like a bunch of noise, but I can't fix the problem. The best way I know how to is to restart the program.

I have tried automating this. I have placed a script in the `/lib/systemd/system-sleep` directory to stop the current running version of `cairo-dock` and restart it under my user account. The problem I have encountered is that cairo-dock doesn't start. I'm not entirely certain, but the script may be firing off before the X server is running.

FWIW, here's the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

case $1 in
  post)
   logger "Now killing cairo-dock."
   killall cairo-dock
   logger "Now starting cairo-dock."
   sudo -u user cairo-dock &
  ;;
esac
```

Another reason for why it's not starting up is that I may not be able to start programs on my account with sudo and systemd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known problem :
[Icons are corrupted after waking up from sleep mode](http://glx-dock.org/ww_page.php?p=Recurrents%20problems&lang=en#29-Icons%20are%20corrupted%20after%20waking%20up%20from%20sleep%20mode).

The help says :

> There is a bug with some icons when resuming from suspend/hibernation
>   but only when using nVidia proprietary drivers.
>
> This bug has already been reported a few years ago but feel free to
>   add new comments there:
>   http://www.nvnews.net/vbulletin/showthread.php?p=2289131 (and/or
>   report this bug to nVidia devs again ).
>
> But there is a workaround: you can launch a daemon which will relaunch
>   the dock when resuming from suspend/hibernation.
>
> - Download this file [here](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~cairo-dock-team/cairo-dock-core/scripts/view/head:/refresh_cd_on_resuming.py) (click on 'download file link on the top) (source: LP: #535065)
> - Launch it at startup ([help here](http://www.glx-dock.org/ww_page.php?p=First%20Steps&lang=en#3-Running%20cairo-dock%20at%20startup)) by adding a new entry with this command:
>     python /path/to/the/file/refresh_cd_on_resuming.py
>
> Note: you can also use a program which does the same thing but coded
>   in C:
>   https://bugs.launchpad.net/cairo-dock-plug-ins/+bug/535065/comments/12
>   .